# How to add view inside of Gallery widget in android

Tags: android, android-widget

G'day!

I wanna do the next:

```
<Gallery ...>
    <TextView ... />
    <TextView ... /> <!-- and etc -->
</Gallery>
```

I've done a custom TextViewAdapter which contains List inside and set that adapter to gallery.

In that case, I have that error: **java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView**

Comment: You can't do that Gallery is not a ViewGroup!!

Comment: Just simply set Adapter to gallery.. Also post code of your activity and adapter class.

Comment: you have to use an adapter that holds the content of your text views

Comment: You can add view by adapter, For example, you want add a textview, so make the adapter getCount is count + 1, then in the getView method, you can return the textview at your wanted postion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not add any view in gallery in xml file.

Using `Adapter` you can add view in gallery.so in

```
public class GalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
```

and in `getView(...) method inflate row`.And row have all your view which you want to add in gallery.and using `Inflator` inflate row.

And setadapter to gallery... `gallery.setAdapter(new GalleryAdapter())`